# Mysql and "count"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a SELECT statement and I have a question. When you do, e.g.:

```
select max(BMI), STDDEV(WEIGHT) FROM MEASUREMENTS where 
      MEASUREMENTS.patient_id='nick' AND 
      MEASUREMENTS.measure_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB("2013-12-30", INTERVAL 6 YEAR) AND "2013-12-30";
```

are rows with 0 counted it as well? If so, how can I exclude them? Because, in my case, 0 means "no measurement was made on that day", so I do not want to be including this day in my total number of results.

Comment: Just add a check to exclude rows where the value is zero

Comment: Agree with @DavidBrossard. Why don't you just add the check to your where clause? Eg: where BMI <> 0 and WEIGHT <>0... or whatever your use case is.

Comment: "0 means no measurement was made on that day" - In a relational database the NULL value is explicitly provided to cater for such a scenario - the way you are using the database is wrong.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @symcbean inserting a record with null's also wouldn't make much sense in a measurement table which records daily patient measurements.. think about it why would there even be a record when there wasn't a measurement for a patient that day.

Comment: @Raymond: No. You are focusing too closely on the problem domain rather than considering how a relational database works. Certainly if the table has no foreign keys, and no other native attributes then it would *appear* to be redundant to insert only a primary key (i.e. the *only* purpose of the record is to record the weight attribute)  - but you did not consider those caveats. And how is inserting a value '0' in **any** way better?

Comment: indeed iam focused on why would you generate daily "default (0 or NULL values)" measure records for every patient existing in your database and update when measures for that day are recorded for a patient that doesn't make sense and i can't think of a valid user case what justifies this approach.. @symcbean well maybe one so you won't need a calendar table/subquery to generate a report but still but still it not totally justifies it still.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: exclude rows that have a value of zero.

Your original statement

```
select max(BMI), STDDEV(WEIGHT) FROM MEASUREMENTS where MEASUREMENTS.patient_id='nick' AND MEASUREMENTS.measure_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB("2013-12-30", INTERVAL 6 YEAR) AND "2013-12-30";
```

Your new statement

```
select max(BMI), STDDEV(WEIGHT) FROM MEASUREMENTS where MEASUREMENTS.patient_id='nick' AND MEASUREMENTS.measure_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB("2013-12-30", INTERVAL 6 YEAR) AND "2013-12-30" AND MEASUREMENTS.WEIGHT <> 0;
```

You just add `AND MEASUREMENTS.WEIGHT <> 0`. You could use greater than 0 too.

Comment: This works very fine, but now I realised that we are only excluding WEIGHT values of 0. What would be the case if we wanted to also exclude BMI values that are 0? It is the case that I can have BMI values <> 0 and a WEIGHT value of 0 in some records, so I can't say WHERE BMI <> 0 AND WEIGHT <> 0, because this will mean bring me the ones that are simultaneously non-zero... What is the correct way to go here?

Comment: Just make an OR statement instead... WHERE BMI <> 0 OR WEIGHT <> 0. Don't forget to upvote / accept the answer, thanks

Comment: No, this does not seem to work... If I do .... AND (BMI <> 0 or WEIGHT <> 0), I get a results table with some records having 0 for BMI and a non-zero value from WEIGHT. However, if I do STDDEV for BMI, these 0 values are counted in, and the STDDEV gets much higher than it should. Are we missing something perhaps?